# React-sound doesn't work on mobile

Tags: audio, reactjs, soundmanager2

I use the npm package ['react-sound'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound) - it's fine and easy to configurate. But! It doesn't work on mobile devices. I tested that on android phones and iPad. 
Maybe someone had the same problem, or idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a restriction on mobile prevent you from playing multiple sounds. To avoid this, you need to set the `ignoreMobileRestrictions` property to true when setting up soundManager2.